# How to Multicast (send) to first NIC?

Tags: c, windows, windows-xp, winsock, multicast

I found recently that if I have a dial-up connection (this is for a kiosk) and a local area network connection, when the dial-up connection is established (with internet access), my multicast sendto would default to the dial-up rather than my LAN NIC. This made the multicast go out to the dial-up connection instead rather than to my LAN which has several multicast subscribers.

I understand that I need to use IP_MULTICAST_IF to set the interface on my multicast socket. Question is how do I enumerate the interfaces and how do I use IP_MULTICAST_IF in setsockopt?
On the kiosk Windows XP Embedded, there's always going to be just one local area connection NIC. How do I get this interface and pass its IP address (is this what IP_MULTICAST_IF is expecting??) to setsockopt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `setsockopt` and `IP_MULTICAST_IF` don't work if `wsock32.dll` is used instead of `ws2_32.dll`. I thought I was doing it wrong when I kept getting `1.0.0.0` as the IP address even when it was something else that I've set with setsockopt. Funny thing is, before the call to `IP_MULTICAST_IF`, it would return `0.0.0.0`, so setsockopt` did change something, just not correctly.

Someone else who had this same problem way back in 2004 - http://us.generation-nt.com/ip-multicast-problem-help-37595922.html. When we `#include "winsock2.h"` we need to use `ws2_32.dll`. However, with C++ Builder, it's impossible to use `ws2_32.dll` when we use `winsock2.h` - the RTL implicitly links in wsock32.dll and you can't link ws2_32.dll even if you explicitly specify `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")`. Embarcadero really need to fix this! Someone in the RTL team must've decided it's *clever* to implicitly include wsock32.dll. The only *'clever'* thing it did was users didn't have to include one line in their code - `#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")`. While they're at that, they might as well include every single DLL files known to mankind.

Comment: You saved my day. it works like a charm on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetAdaptersAddresses()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915.aspx) to enumerate all available interface IP addresses.

`IP_MULTICAST_IF` is for IPv4 addresses only.  It expects you to pass a `DWORD` value containing the desired IPv4 address (in network byte order) to `setsockopt()`, eg:

```
DWORD dwIP = ...;
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&dwIP, sizeof(dwIP));
```

Comment: I know how to enumerate IP addresses but my question was how do I get the local area connection NIC IP?

Comment: GetAdaptersAddresses() tells you what type of interface each address belongs to. You can differentiate between dialup and LAN connections with that.

Comment: `setsockopt IP_MULTICAST_IF` doesn't work with C++ Builder. It links to wsock32.dll instead (we need ws2_32.dll to make it work).

Comment: That would work but I shouldn't have to. Anyway I found what the problem was -- import32.lib brings in wsock32.dll implicitly so we're all forced to use it even when we choose to use ws2_32.dll. The RTL team really need to fix this. I've recompiled the RTL to make it work.