# How to specify the multicast SEND interface in Python?

Tags: python, linux, multicast, ipv4

There is quite a few examples to RECEIVE multicast messages with a spcific network interface (NIC, e.g. eth0, 127.0.0.1 etc). However, there is few discussion/examples about how to SEND multicast (UDP) messages to a specific interface, e.g. local loop (127.0.0.1) instead of eth0 by default.

Background: RedHat Linux, Python, 224.1.1.1 5005

Python Code example in
[Multicast in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603852/multicast-in-python)

A similar discuss for IPv6
[How to send multicast packets via a specfic interface in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798165/how-to-send-multicast-packets-via-a-specfic-interface-in-linux)

A similar discuss for Windows 
[How to Multicast (send) to first NIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681703/how-to-multicast-send-to-first-nic)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question that you've linked [How to Multicast (send) to first NIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681703/how-to-multicast-send-to-first-nic) mentions that you could use `IP_MULTICAST_IF`:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton(addr))
```

Comment: Don't forget to increase TTL

Comment: @e271p314: I don't remember what it is about but [the code example that is linked in the question appears to handle TTL already (since 2009)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603852/multicast-in-python). My answer sets a single option i.e., it only answers the question in the title.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot, your answer is correct. when I tried it I saw I didn't get the multicast and was breaking my head to understand what is the issue. My TTL was configured to 2 because I copy pasted the code. After some time I realized from this [link](http://svn.python.org/projects/stackless/trunk/Demo/sockets/mcast.py) That I need to "Increase to reach other networks" So I just though that if might be usful to other which came to your answer get this tip too :-)