# Boost asio socket multicast send data with a specific ethernet interface

Tags: c++, boost, multicast, asio

```
boost::asio::ip::address_v4 local_interface = 
boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(ip);
boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface option(local_interface);
sock.set_option(option); //set interface
```

It does not work! I used wireshark to capture data, but the data source interface is not the local_interface, why??? and How to make it working?

Comment: struct in_addr interface_addr;
            interface_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
            if (-1 == setsockopt(sock.native_handle(), IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char*)&interface_addr, sizeof(interface_addr)))
            {
                LOG_INFO("setsockopt IP_MULTICAST_IF error!");
            }

Comment: set IP_MULTICAST_IF also invalid!

Comment: Can you please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: io_service io;
    ip::udp::socket sock(io);
    ip::udp::endpoint endpoint_group(ip::address::from_string(group_ip), port);
 sock.open(ip::udp::v4());                         
 sock.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::send_buffer_size(1024*1024));
 sock.set_option(ip::multicast::enable_loopback(false));
 sock.set_option(ip::multicast::outbound_interface(ip::address::from_string(ip).to_v4()));

Comment: I have two computers, both have 2 network cards. I set the specific interface on one success,  the other is invalid.  but my friend used libuv library to set on the host success. The libuv inside use setsockopt set IP_MULTICAST_IF.  I use setsockopt ,but failed! I suspect there's something wrong with the system?

Comment: Still it lacks a detailed explanation what it does not work and what you did expect.

Comment: On Windows system , I use winsock2.h and  pragma coment ws2_32.lib 。 My code link WSOCK32.DLL(Already exists and I don't know how to introduce it ) and WS2_32.DLL 。 It seems like that:  when I use setsockopt to set IP_MULTICAST_IF  the WSOCK32.DLL will make it not work. But when I use ws2_32.DLL in a new and separate project, it works!  So  I changed my code use winsock.h  instead of winsock2.h. By the way, there is no such problem on Linux system

Comment: I don't know how to use winsock2.h to avoid this problem: WSOCK32.DLL and WS2_32.DLL both exist in a program. Setting IP_MULTICAST_IF socket will have no effect.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681703/how-to-multicast-send-to-first-nic

Answer (score 0):

WSOCK32.DLL WS2_32.DLL both exist in a program. We can set VS project linker input: Ignore specific default libraries(the WSOCK32.DLL).